# How to set visible attribute to field with condition in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

How is it possible in rails_admin set visible attribute depends on other objects fields?
If i trying to use `bindings[:object]` all fields are nil, because in list we have something like Model.new on every record. The problem is only with list action. other actions working fine.

Im trying this:

```
field :public do
        visible do
          p bindings[:object]
        end
      end
```

Maybe there is a way to get access to object from list action? Thanks

Comment: The list view is a table with one row for each record, what would you expect to that cell that corresponds to your public field if the object is nil or new? Be empty? You might want to configure the pretty_value instead of the visible attribute.